# Регулировка оборотов кулеров с двумя пинами

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, администрирование, железо

**Коротко:** Сильно шумят кулеры сервера.

**Подробно:** Купила сервер, в нем стоит ряд из 6 кулеров на 12 вольт. Эти кулеры очень громко гудят, прям вот очень.
Все кулеры припаяны двумя проводами к плате, которая в свою очередь через molex подключается к блоку питания.

**Что делала:**

- Пробовала менять местами пины в молекс так, что б подавалось не 12в,
  а 5в. Но это помогло снизить шум максимум на 10%, сервер все так же
  громко гудит, хотя температура процессоров не больше 20 градусов.
- Искала схемки в иннете, но ничего толкового не
  нашла. Везде схемы на 1 кулер максимум, а у меня их 6...

Как я понимаю, мне нужно подключить питание от блока питания (т.к. не уверенна, что материнка выдержит 6 кулеров одновременно), а управлять оборотами с материнской платы. Помогите найти что то толковое или подскажите как такую кракозябру собрать...

Руки у меня из более-менее правильного места, паять умею, по схеме могу собрать что-то рабочее.

Если это нужно, то на сервере стоит Ubuntu.

<sub>Извиняюсь, что немного не по теме сайта, не знаю куда еще написать...</sub>

Comment: пожалуйста, не лезьте без допуска и образования в это. да. в мыслях может много крутиться исполнимого и выполнимого. но, допустим, вы нашли заветный трёх-пиновый разьём и подлкючили, как "образованный" 6 новых 3-пиновых кулеров... ощущаете ошибку? далее, микросхемы перейдут в менее охлаждаемое состояние, уменьшая срок службы, при полном отключении ваших вентиляторов плата скорее всего выйдет из строя полностью. почему?

Comment: сфоткай плату с молексом с 2х сторон

Comment: Пусть себе сильно шумит, но охождается, чем не шумит и греется. А вообще вам к сис-админам сюда, https://serverfault.com/ это их тематика.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH сервер стоит в комнате с температурой 10°С. Сомневаюсь, что ему нужно крутить кулеры с такой силой) На всех датчиках при максимальной нагрузке температура выше 14-20°С не поднимается

Comment: Если сервер стоечный - он не должен быть тихим. В серверных никто не спит - поэтому вентиляторы по 10к-15к оборотов - вполне нормальное явление. Хочешь тишину - покупай обычный комп и большие радиаторные (не водные) охлаждалки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для управления оборотами нужен 4х пиновый вывод на вентилятор. На плате куда впаяны вентиляторы возможно есть MOSFET.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К нему нужно подключить 4ый пин с материнки (обозначенный как PWM)

Посмотри - возможно не хватает перемычки с этой платы питания на материнку. Если перемычка есть, то смотри на каком она разъёме и пробуй его запустить через pwmconfig.

Для двухпроводных моторов схема такая (лучше конечно по отдельному полевику на каждый мотор), но грубо - вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С изоляцией питания модулем (защита от пробоя и кривых рук)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нужно откалибровать через pwmconfig

Не помню инвертированное управление на материнке или нет, но если инвертированное, то [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ПС. схемы условные! если не готовым модулем, то уточни обвязку и схему включения конкретных транзисторов

Comment: Возможно не совсем понятно описала... Дело в том, что на плате нет молекса. На материнке есть 2 разъема на 4 пина под кулеры, но они пустые, а сами кулеры питаются изначально от блока питания. Такая схема подключения через мосфет будет работать, если подключить питание и землю с блока питания, а управляющий сигнал с материнки?

Comment: "Все кулеры припаяны двумя проводами к плате, " - я об этой плате

Comment: на этой плате поищи мосфет. если он там есть, то надо кинуть перемычку на материнку.

Comment: если нет, то разрезай минусовой провод и припаивай туда, лучше изолированный модуль https://aliexpress.ru/popular/mosfet-module-isolate.html